# How to restore original position after translation using TranslateTransform? (Windows Phone C#)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have an `Image` which I am translating along the `X`, with the `Drag` gesture. I am handling the `DragDelta` event for translating the image using the `TranslateTransform`  object like this.
`translate.X += e.HorizontalChange;`
Now I want to restore the original position of the `Image` on the `DragCompleted` event. What I noticed was that the `Margin` property is not changed during translation. So which property (or possibly method) can I use to restore the original position of the `Image`
Thank you in advance

Comment: can you give your sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transforms, such as your translate transform, happen *on top of* your other layouting (such as margins etc.)

To reset the position, just restore the translate transform to whatever it was before you started dragging.

```
// _originalX and _originalY were initialized in your DragStart handler
translate.X = _originalX;
translate.Y = _originalY
```

Comment: Thanks. Works. I forgot about the DragStarted event.